# Problems compiling Windows 8 Metro Application

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create a Windows 8 Metro Application using Grid View with Visual Studio 11 Preview, but when the project template for the Grid View is finished loading, I get inexplicable errors.

I get something about makepri.exe not being found.

Comment: Have you seen http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winappswithcsharp/thread/5086f4a3-dc02-4107-be96-c0d50c18b650?

Comment: Probably the same mistake I made, not having a dual-sided DVD burner.  Only the .iso with both Win8 and VS2011 works well.

Comment: nope, haven't seen that.. but yeah I only have the 32-bit version, i couldn't make a USB bootable iso > 4GB, so I could only do the 32-bit or else I would've done the 64-bit. Thanks though. I'll just have to deal with it until they find a solution to the 32-bit.

Comment: @AmitApollo - Do you lack a big enough device because it being greater then 4GB shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: for some reason the 64-bit iso wouldn't install properly using the Windows 7 USB tool. I don't know if it was the limitation from my 8GB thumb drive or what. It's one of those cheap DANE ELEC 8GB thumb drives.

Comment: You can install Windows 8 without any dvds or flash drives. I created a virtual disk (vhd), copied installation files there  and attached it during loading of the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gabe actually answered this, but 32-bit Windows 8 Preview, can not compile Metro Apps at this time. Bummer.